# add numbers in an array with PHP

Tags: php

I want all of the elements in the array to be added together, but this doesn't seem to be working.

```
    <?php

    function mimic_array_sum($array) {
        foreach($array as $total) {
            $total = $total + $total;
        }
        return $total;
    }
    $var = array(1,2,3,4,5);
    $total = mimic_array_sum($var);
    echo $total;
?>
```

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to be working" mean?  What results are you expecting?  The #1 problem you have is that you're using `$total` as both a loop variable and an accumulator.

Comment: You're overwriting your $total variable on each iteration

Comment: Related: [Php foreach- Why it doesn't override the array value while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12313107/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$total = $total + $total` --> well, there's your problem...

The `$total` variable gets overwritten on each loop through the array.
Assign a separate variable for each number in the array, like so:

```
function mimic_array_sum($array) {
    $total = 0;
    foreach($array as $number) {
        $total = $total + $number;
    }
    return $total;
}
$var = array(1,2,3,4,5);
echo mimic_array_sum($var);
```

Although the point of this is not clear to me... You might as well use the php-function **array_sum**...

```
$var = array(1,2,3,4,5);
echo array_sum($var);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$total = array_reduce(
    $var,
    function($sum, $value) {
        return $sum + $value;
    }
);
```

though why not simply use array_sum()?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**array_sum**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) — Calculate the sum of values in an array

```
$var = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$total = array_sum($var);
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php

    function mimic_array_sum($array) {
            $total = 0;
        foreach($array as $elem) {
            $total += is_numeric($elem) ? $elem : 0;
        }
        return $total;
    }
    $var = array(1,2,3,4,5);
    $total = mimic_array_sum($var);
    echo $total;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following, you have to take separate variable to do so. Or else you can use `array_sum()`

```
function mimic_array_sum($array) {
    $test = 0;
    foreach($array as $total) {
        $test = intval($test) + intval($total);
    }
    return $test;
}
$var = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$total = mimic_array_sum($var);
echo $total;
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
echo "sum is:".array_sum($a);
?>
```

See [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Comment: This wouldn't work. It'll just output some Array to String conversion errors.

Comment: @AmalMurali Thanks buddy I forget to write array_sum even I have attached the correct manual link :P

Comment: Yeah, should work now, but doesn't actually answer the OP's question though.

Comment: Focus on the title `add numbers in an array with PHP`